What's the correct data structure and format to fine-tune OpenAI assistant as a vector file?
I'm trying to fine-tune an assistant that depends on gpt-3.5-turbo model with numbers and bullets but bullets never show up. I created both docx and txt files with different data format like:
Title: Fine-Tuning Data for Laravel

Context:
User is asking about implementing the repository design pattern in Laravel.

User Input:
How do I implement the repository design pattern in Laravel?

Expected Response:
To implement the repository design pattern in Laravel, follow these steps:

1- Create a Repository Interface
    * Define an interface that specifies the methods for interacting with your data models.

2- Create a Repository Class
    * Implement the interface in a concrete class.

3- Bind the Repository in a Service Provider
    * Bind the interface to the implementation in a service provider.

4- Use the Repository in Controllers
    * Inject the repository interface in your controllers.

5- Test the Implementation
    * Ensure that your repository pattern is correctly set up by writing tests.

I also tried:
1-  Create a Repository Interface:
•   Define an interface that specifies the methods for interacting with your data models.
2-  Create a Repository Class:
•   Implement the interface in a concrete class.

I tried to press Enter and Shift+Enter I tried different indentation but all what I get is the same response:
The steps to implement the repository design pattern in Laravel are:

1 Create a Repository Interface: Define an interface that specifies the methods for interacting with your data models.
2 Create a Repository Class: Implement the interface in a concrete class.
3 Bind the Repository in a Service Provider: Bind the interface to the implementation in a service provider.
4 Use the Repository in Controllers: Inject the repository interface in your controllers.
5 Test the Implementation: Ensure that your repository pattern is correctly set up by writing tests[1].

I just started learning this but didn't find a good tutorial about formatting data. I don't use Python for this but I directly upload the document to the vector-files and test via the playground of the assistant.
How to correctly format the data to return numbers and bullets below each one?
I also tried this format in a docx file:

and that's what I get:


Wait, are you asking here how to format text in Word?
